# Cannot connect to local postgresql DB using DBeaver

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, dbeaver

I'm trying to connect to a postgresql database which is in localhost:5432 but I keep getting the error: 
FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "".

I installed Postgres11 on virtual machine running Centos7. Created a database through command line, with the name business_db.

I've checked and postgresql is running in localhost:5432.

My pg_hba.conf file is like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           ident
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

The pg_ident.conf file doesn't hold any configurations:

```
# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------

# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
```

The database exists as shown by the command:

[image: Database list]

I'm logged into the system as "dev" user but., whatever I try while testing connection whit DBeaver, I allways get the error:

[image: ERROR]

I also tried to set User as postgres and use my system password but get the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: Still true for DBeaver. I tried to upgrade driver version, but could not find clear guidelines how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use JDBC, you have to use password authentication. Neither `ident` nor `peer` will work for that.

You will need to add, e.g.:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32           md5
```

at the top of your pb_hba.conf

(replace `md5` with `scram-sha-256` if you are using that)

Comment: Preliminary to this record in pg_hba.conf some configuration steps related to database itself (password encryption method) should be done as described in article https://stackoverflow.com/a/64336274/1017684

Answer (score 3):

Change the `ident` to `trust` if you don't want to enter a password or to `md5` if you want to enter a password.

Then reload the PostgreSQL server.

Answer (score 2):

In (Ubuntu OS), change (or set) password in this way to solve this problem:

1- In terminal, run this command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

2- Then run this command:

```
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'your_password';
```

Answer (score 0):

remove any spaces from your password, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

1.Find the port running postgres using:

```
sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
```

**Note that postgres may NOT always run at default port 5432. It may change to other port than default port 5432. In new version of postgres, it changes to 5434.**

2.login to postgres with default user and then change password as desired:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
\password
```

3.Enter above set up username, password and port to DBeaver. It will run as normal.